# Console.ReadLine() without line break at the end?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Question is simple.

When I use -

```
Console.ReadLine()
```

The next thing printed on the console will on the next line.

Is there any way to continue printing on that line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _You_ are writing on the console? Or is it a other application?

Comment: Do you mean `Console.Write()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

Console.SetCursorPosition (x, y)

Answer (score 6):

Please check,

Console.Read();

This would not cause new line or line break.

Comment: This does indeed cause a line break when I press Enter to end it.

Comment: Use esc key to exit, or if you are forced to use enter for exit, Use ReadKey function to capture the enter event and exit the application, for detail open http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx

Comment: I dont' want to exit the application, I want to simply capture a string without being forced to go down a line.

Comment: Yes, you can do this by capturing event, please check the above url, you can go back to previous line on clicking enter, so in enter event you can write the code to do a backspace when it is pressed, so whenever you will press enter, it will go the new line and back space function will again move it to the same position, after that you can store that string in your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    var s = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.CursorTop--;
    Console.CursorLeft = s.Length;
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

Comment: The `Console.CursorTop--;` does indeed go up a line, but it makes the following text overwrite the existing line. `Console.CursorLeft = ...` seems to have no effect, no matter what I write in there.