# C# Visual Studio IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I am a college student and new to C#. Is it possible to make the output in one line? You can see in the output image below:

instead of like this

```
Name:User

Annual Sale:$68000

Sales Commission:$6800
```

become

```
Name: User     Annual Sale:$68000     Sales Commission:$6800
```

Below is my coding:

```
Console.Write("\n Employee Name: ");

name[a] = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write(" Annual Sale: $");

sales[a]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You just need:

```
Console.Write("\n Employee Name: ");

name[a] = Console.ReadLine();
// here you reset cursor position to previous line, at the end of it
Console.SetCursorPosition("\n Employee Name: ".Length + name[a].Length, Console.CursorTop - 1);

Console.Write(" Annual Sale: $");

sales[a] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

[Useful SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818678/console-readline-without-line-break-at-the-end/7818724)

Answer (score 0):

Please use a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder) to frame the text and then use the `Console.Write` to write the complete string.

```
        string[] name = new string[1];
        string[] sales = new string[1];
        string[] comm = new string[1];
        StringBuilder sbWrite = new StringBuilder();
        name[0] = Console.ReadLine();
        sbWrite.Append("Employee Name : " + name[0]);
        sales[0] = Console.ReadLine();
        sbWrite.Append(" Annual Sale :  " + sales[0]);
        comm[0] = Console.ReadLine();
        sbWrite.Append(" Sales Commission : " + comm[0]);

        Console.WriteLine(sbWrite.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: ... and where you can enter data?

Comment: hi, i have added the complete code, can you please check

Comment: You missed the `ReadLine()`s. And a StringBuilder isn't really useful here.

Comment: okay, actual code in the question has a for loop and it has to concatenate string values, so I thought the StringBuilder would be useful. Let me check again.